# Scaling a complex responsive header

Tags: css

I'm practicing the one thing that scares the hell out of me: responsive CSS.

I made a header like this one, mostly via use of positive/negative margins. However, it becomes a mess once I start changing the viewport's dimensions.

[image: complex header example picture]

Were it just a simple `h1` (such as only the 'Grandmaster'), I'd use `font-size: 5vw`, and it'd scale. However, since it's more complex, just throwing `vw` units around doesn't help.

What is the best way to have a complex header like this scale well across all screen sizes?

My idea:

- Make it either a SVG or a JPG, then have a `h1` with `display:none` or some other trick (such as moving it off screen with position:absolute) for SEO. The pro is that making it an image is probably the easiest way to let it scale everywhere properly. The con is that, as far as I'm concerned, it still hurts SEO.

Is there one estabilished way to deal with such a case?

Comment: insert your code pls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many strategies you could go about this one, since it is very opinionated, the best solution would be to keep the text, use some `span` for the various parts of the text and use `em` units to size them, then just change the `font-size` on the parent element and the various parts will scale accordingly. Use media queries `@media` to change the parent element's `font-size` in critical breakpoints.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.header__title--content {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 50px 0;
  background-color: red;
  background: url('https://picsum.photos/2000?grayscale');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  font-family: 'Times New Roman', serif;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 400px) {
  .header__title--content {
    font-size: 3em;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
  .header__title--content {
    font-size: 4em;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
  .header__title--content {
    font-size: 6em;
  }
}

.header__title {
  display: grid;
  margin-bottom: 0.1em;
}

.header__title--element-one {
  font-size: .75em;
  margin-left: 1.7em;
  line-height: .9em;
}

.header__title--element-two {
  font-size: .5em;
  margin-left: 2.5em;
  line-height: .6em;
}

.header__title--element-three {
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: .6em;
}

.header__subtitle {
  font-size: .4em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 1em;
}
```

```html
<hgroup class="header__title--content">
  <h1 class="header__title"><span class="header__title--element-one">Story </span><span class="header__title--element-two">of the </span><span class="header__title--element-three">Grandmaster</span></h1>
  <h2 class="header__subtitle">bobby fisher, the some content goes here</h2>
</hgroup>
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm controlling the font-size on the master element via `vw`, this way media queries aren't even needed. Splendid!

Answer (score 0):

try using css media queries for example：

```
h1{
 font-size: 30px
 }
@media screen and (max-width: 790px) {
  h1{
   font-size: 15px
  }
}
```

@media screen and (max-width: 790px) this means For screens that are 790px or less, set the font size to 15 px you can read more about it here https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp